# Probability in a game of bridge

Tags: probability

I was given the following question:

> In the game of bridge there are four players-A, B, C and D. Players A
>   and C are partners and players B and D are partners. Each player gets
>   $13$ cards. If one player and his partner have $9$ spades between
>   them, what is the probability that the $4$ other spades are split
>   three and one between the two other players?

**My work:**

I treat players A and C as one player - player $1$, and players B and
D I treat as Player $2$.

I thought the answer should be
$$2\cdot\frac{\binom{13}{12}\binom{39}{14}+\binom{13}{10}\binom{39}{16}}{\binom{52}{26}}$$

My reasoning is:

1) I double by $2$ because I assume that it is player $1$ with the
given $9$ spades, but the problem is symmetric

2) If the spades are split in such a way then player $1$ have $10$
spades or $12$ spades. I then choose the spades player $1$ will
have and I complete his hand to $26$ cards from the non-spade cards

3) $\binom{52}{26}$ is the number of ways to choose a hand for player
1

However, I was told that my answer is wrong (I used a calculator to
compare with another answer which claims the probability is $0.5$).

Can someone please point out my mistake ? did I not account for something
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore the partnership with 9 spades.  The others have 4 spades and 22 non-spades between them.  You can select a hand for one partner in ${26 \choose 13}$ ways.  He can get 1 spade in ${4 \choose 1}{22 \choose 12}$ ways, and can get 3 spades in ${4 \choose 3}{22 \choose 10}$ ways.  These are exclusive, so we can add them to get $\frac {{4 \choose 1}{22 \choose 12}+{4 \choose 3}{22 \choose 10}}{26 \choose 13}\approx 49.74\%$ as seen in [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284%2abinomial%20%2822,12%29%20%2b%204%2abinomial%2822,10%29%29/binomial%2826,13%29)

Comment: Why do you choose to ignore the partnership with 9 spades ? Isn't this the same calculation basically ? why the number of ways to choose a hand is $\binom{26}{13}$ and not $\binom{52}{13}$ ?

Comment: @Belgi:  Because we don't care what their hands look like.  We just give them 9 spades and 17 non-spades, leaving the deck I described to be distributed between the pair with 4 spades.

Comment: @Belgi: If you want to take the hands of $A$ and $B$ into account, you can think of this as a conditional probability argument. **Given** that $A$ and $B$ have certain hands, where the combined number of spades happens to be $9$, we can compute the probability of a $3$-$1$ or $1$-$3$ split for $C$ and $D$. This should be **roughly** (but not very roughly) the probability of $1$ head and $3$ tails or $3$ tails and $1$ head in $4$ tosses of a fair coin.

Comment: In fact it is very close, as the coin flip is exactly $50\%$  The only difference is you "use up spaces" in the hand that gets $3$ spades, which lowers the chance a bit.

Comment: Ross what do you mean by "use up spaces" ? I got everything down exept why don't we need to muliply by $2$...I'm always confused by that part

Comment: @AndréNicolas - your comment was very helpfull, thank you!

Comment: Worth noting that the probability they have two spades each is about $40.7\%$ so rather smaller